# $h \simeq \Sigma \omega$? where $h:S^7 \to S^4$ the Hopf map and $\omega$ is a generator of $\pi_6(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It is ture?

How prove that?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask#motivation

Comment: I don't think this is true. $\pi_7S^4 = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/{12}$. Probably $\omega$ suspends to the generator of the $\mathbb{Z}/12$ summand, and the Hopf map is the other.

Comment: Right... I think the way to see this is to look at the EHP sequence, since $\pi_7S^4$ is right on the edge.

Comment: How about accepting some of the answers to your previous questions, or at least engaging with them, before asking yet another new question?

Answer (score 9):

No.  The Hopf map in $\pi_7(S^4)$ is usually called $\nu$, and the generator of $\pi_6(S^3)$ is usually called $\nu'$.  The Hopf invariant $H:\pi_7(S^4)\to\pi_7(S^7)=\mathbb{Z}$ has $H(\nu)=1$ but $H\Sigma=0$ so in particular $H(\Sigma(\nu'))=0$ and $\Sigma(\nu')$ cannot be equal to $\nu$.  Or you can just argue that $\nu'$ has finite order so $\Sigma(\nu')$ also has finite order, but the order of $\nu$ is infinite.

The canonical reference is Toda's book "Composition methods in the homotopy groups of spheres".  Alternatively, you can download a Mathematica representation of most of the results in that book from http://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/toda/.